# Ruby 2.4 module name conflict with my model class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, upgrade, ruby-2.4

I'm  upgrading Ruby's version from 2.3.8 to 2.4.4 on Rails 5.2.3.

When I start the application I get this error:

`` app/models/warning.rb:1:in `<main>': Warning is not a class (TypeError) ``

when called on console:
`Warning.class => Module`

But in fact it is one of my models called `Warning`.

I saw in released notes an introduction to a new **module** on ruby 2.4 called `Warning`.
but how can I avoid this conflict without renaming my **model** with migrations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Warning` module is used for overriding ruby `warn` method. To temporarily get around the error - you can undefine the constant before defining your model:

```rb
Object.send(:remove_const, :Warning)
```

runnable test:

```rb
require "bundler/inline"
gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "activerecord", "5.2.3"
  gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.6"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table(:warnings, force: true){|t| t.string  :name }
end

RubyWarning = Warning
Object.send(:remove_const, :Warning)

class Warning < ActiveRecord::Base
end

def RubyWarning.warn(str)
  puts "still works: #{str}"
end

class SomeTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_stuff
    wrn = Warning.create name: 'test'
    assert_equal(wrn.name, 'test')
    warn "Test warn"
  end
end
```